# Problem ANDROID_HOME when build APK iOnic

Tags: environment-variables, ubuntu-sdk

I have a problem when I try build apk from my iOnic app.

When I send `$sudo ionic cordova build --release android --verbose`

Return this:

```
**Failed to find 'ANDROID_HOME' environment variable.** Try setting it manually.
**Failed to find 'android' command in your 'PATH'.** 
Try update your 'PATH' to include path to valid SDK directory.
CordovaError: Failed to find 'ANDROID_HOME' environment variable. Try setting it manually.
Failed to find 'android' command in your 'PATH'. Try update your 'PATH' to include path to valid SDK directory.
    at /home/sion/lab/mifasol_dd/mifasol-beta/platforms/android/cordova/lib/check_reqs.js:297:19
    at _fulfilled (/home/sion/lab/mifasol_dd/mifasol-beta/platforms/android/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:834:54)
    at self.promiseDispatch.done (/home/sion/lab/mifasol_dd/mifasol-beta/platforms/android/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:863:30)
    at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (/home/sion/lab/mifasol_dd/mifasol-beta/platforms/android/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:796:13)
    at /home/sion/lab/mifasol_dd/mifasol-beta/platforms/android/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:857:14
    at runSingle (/home/sion/lab/mifasol_dd/mifasol-beta/platforms/android/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:137:13)
    at flush (/home/sion/lab/mifasol_dd/mifasol-beta/platforms/android/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:125:13)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:131:7)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:180:9)
[ERROR] An error occurred while running subprocess cordova.

        cordova build android --release --verbose exited with exit code 1.
```

When I check ANDROID_HOME , there are a correct PATH

ANDROID_HOME=/home/sion/Android/Sdk

I don't know what happend, Can you help me please?

Regards

Answer (score 0):

When you invoke any command via `sudo`, `sudo`, for security reasons, resets the command's environment. See `man sudo;man sudoers`.

Must you use `sudo` for this? Why?

Could you achieve the same thing by finding the group access, and adding yourself to the group?

```
ls -ld
sudo adduser $USER group
```

For now, and this is NOT the recommended way (because it's probably incomplete),

```
sudo env PATH=$PATH ANDROID_HOME=$ANDROID_HOME $(type -p ionic) cordoba ...
```